# Could we find the n-th term formula for recursive formula $x_{n+1} = {x_n{({x_n \over {x_n+7}}+43)^3}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I have the recursive sequence

$x_0=a$

$x_{n+1} = {x_n{({x_n \over {x_n+7}}+43)^3}}$

could we find the n-th term formula, as we have such for geometric progression.

May be you have any suggestion for good book where such question investigated.

Comment: How do you know the closed-form expression for $x_n$ exists?

Comment: @NN2 if I had know it, I doesn't asked for help, I think it should be exist :)

Comment: I thought you know the problem has closed-form solution but you don’t know how to obtain this solution. But it turns out that you don’t know whether a closed form solution exists. In thasmt case, you can compute the terms with numericsl methods.

Comment: @NN2 it is how it is works now. It computed. For optimization reasons we try found the closed-form.